# Jquery - Compare Custom Object Property Based On User Chocie

Tags: jquery, properties

I am trying to create a dynamic search which returns matching items in the array based on the users selection of property and search query. My object has the following property names:

```
_id,
_name,
_engine,
_version,
_price,
_recalled
```

The user selects a search by property value from a drop down;

```
var PropertyName = "_" + $('#_options').find(":selected").text().toLowerCase();
```

I am using the $.grep function to compare and trying to allow the e[0].[MyObjectPropety] to manipulated.

How would I achieve this based on the users preference?

```
var Items = $.grep(List, function (e)
{
  return e[0].UsersDropDownSelection == 'UsersInput'
}
```

So if the user had chosen 'Engine' in the drop down, the code would perform like this:

```
var Items = $.grep(List, function (e)
{
  return e[0]._engine == 'UsersInput'
}
```

I am unsure how this could work without iterating over each item using key and element to compare. This needs to be complete dynamic so no switch/case statements or nested if's can be used.

Thanks for any help in advance and I hope this made sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array notation for accessing object properties via name as string. If `e[0]` is an object, and the following conditions exist:

```
var elem = e[0];
var PropertyName = '_engine';
var hasEngine = elem.hasOwnProperty(PropertyName); // is true
```

then `elem[PropertyName]` should equal `e[0]._engine`.

We can assert this with a simple test:

```
var e = [ {_engine: 'im an engine'} ];

var elem = e[0];
var PropertyName = '_engine';
var hasEngine = elem.hasOwnProperty(PropertyName);

console.log(hasEngine); // prints true
console.log(elem[PropertyName]); // prints "im an engine"
```

Thus, your final code would be something like:

```
var Items = $.grep(List, function (e)
{
    var elem = e[0];
    if (elem.hasOwnProperty(UsersDropDownSelection) {
        return elem[UsersDropDownSelection] == 'UsersInput';
    } else {
        return false; // should really do some exception here!
    }
}
```

Comment: Oddly this wasn't working at home. I tried on JFiddle and it worked. Thanks for this answer as its correct!